# Magento 2.4.2-p1 - Redis cache full

Tags: cache, magento2.4, redis, magento2.4.2

Just upgraded my DEV server to Magento 2.4.2-p1.

I am very confused about why its using HUGE amounts of RAM when reindexing Catalog Search.

You can see on this screenshot it's filled 115GB of RAM.

[image: Redis Cache Filling Up RAM]

The catalog is big (300k +). This issue is not happening on current PRODUCTION site which is running on 2.3.3.

I did

```
redis-cli flushall
```

when I was upgrading Magento. So it cant really be an issue with duplicate keys.

My env.php settings for cache look like this (both sites use the same settings):

```
'cache' => [
    'frontend' => [
        'default' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'database' => '0',
                'port' => '6379'
            ],
            'id_prefix' => '123_'
        ],
        'page_cache' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '6379',
                'database' => '1',
                'compress_data' => '0'
            ],
            'id_prefix' => '123_'
        ]
    ]
],
```

We're running Varnish as Full Page Cache, but its not connected yet for testing purposes.

I mentioned this cache overload in my other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278489/docker-compose-mnt-sdb-is-always-full/68287144#68287144

^^^ here because cache was set to file storage it would fill up the hard-drive within 15 minutes. It would create 100GB just like that.

I was thinking maybe it's using DDL cache is doing this?

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html

[image: Magento DDL Cache]

UPDATE:

After about 2 hours, Redis finally blew up and crashed:

[image: Redis crashed]

It looks like maybe the plugin that is managing the ElasticSearch + Catalog Search indexes is not actually saving the data into the DB? I contacted devs to see what they say.

UPDATE:
Looks like I'm not alone in this. There is a GitHub issue with other people reporting the same issue:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32118

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to disable the CSP module for the issue to stop.

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Csp
```